# Instantiation IGroupPolicyObject fiailed with 0x800736B1

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winapi, group-policy

I want to set some config for group policy, using code found on the internet.

```
::CoInitialize(NULL);
IGroupPolicyObject* pObj = NULL;
            hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_GroupPolicyObject, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IGroupPolicyObject, (LPVOID *)&pObj);
            if (FAILED(hr))
            {
                // hr = print
                break;
            }
```

As I run this in my win10 it works.But when I use the same code in win7, CoCreateInstance returns 0x800736B1 and IGroupPolicyObject instantiation failed.

I thought gpedit.dll version is too old, but I run in server2008 it works.

And I follow the errcode using sxstrace.exe, the log shows:

> INFO: Parsing Manifest File C:\Windows\System32\GPEdit.dll.   INFO:
> Manifest Definition Identity is (null). ERROR: Activation Context
> generation failed. End Activation Context Generation.

Not useful for me.

Maybe some services is not running? I don't know.
Any thoughts much thanks

Comment: See [activation contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/activation-contexts).

Comment: As I run this code as service(SYSTEM session), it fails.But run as exe the user priviledge is not enough to access it,permission denied.  Only run as Admin works. It feels like system session doesn't have COM config of group policy, and normal user doesn't have permission